# Difference between "polemical" and "contentious"

Tags: meaning, synonyms

Is there any difference between "polemical" and "contentious"?

Example sentences describing people:

- Daniel sometimes could be quite polemical.
- A contentious person is someone who likes to argue or fight.

Example sentences describing things:

- It is easy to be polemical about communism.
- The contentious vote has raised tensions in the South American country.

Can't see any difference between these two words...

Comment: Yes. Polemical is stronger in most contexts insofar as it suggests a particular aggressiveness or intent to argue a point forcefully. In that connection, it's more naturally suited to describe an active subject. So, whereas it's possible to describe a book or person as being polemical (i.e., it sets out to a argue for a position) or contentious (i.e., it embraces various points and gives rise to debate), it is infelicitous to say that an issue is polemical. An issue or topic may be contentious, but it just sits there and isn't polemical.

Comment: The Wikipedia article, and the [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/polemic) explanation bring out the hostility / belligerence denoted in polemics and the closely related adjective. There are strong hints of oratory, pontification. It's a very formal word. / Contentious is (in this sense) a pretty close synonym of 'quarrelsome', more everyday and more strongly associated with grumpiness than fiery radicalism.